# C# YouTube Downloader

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube

Пишу скачиватель видео с ютуба на либе `VideoLibrary`. В интерфейсе есть прогрессбар и две кнопки + еще поле для ввода, одна кнопка это скачать, а вторая указать папку куда скачивать. Я привязал к кнопке выбора папки диалоговое окно, но не могу вывести от туда результат и поместить туда путь до папки, а код указанный ниже выдает ошибку

```
Нет перегруженного метода для "downloadik_Click", который соответствует делегату "RoutedEventHandler"
```

```
using VideoLibrary;
using Ookii.Dialogs;
using Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf;
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
            folderDialog.SelectedPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            WinForms.DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void downloadik_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, string result)
        {
            string link = url.ToString();
            var youTube = YouTube.Default;

            var video = YouTube.Default.GetAllVideos(link).First(v => v.Resolution == 720);
            var audio = YouTube.Default.GetVideo(link);

            byte[] bytesvideo = video.GetBytes();
            File.WriteAllBytes(result + video.FullName, bytesvideo);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы добавили аргумент  `string result` в метод `downloadik_Click` ? это же обработчик события нажатия кнопки, он принимает только методы с набором аргументов `object sender, RoutedEventArgs e`

Comment: Я так понимаю у вас WPF ? укажите плиз тег вопроса wpf, тег youtube мне кажется стоит убрать, он по сути не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: Как же у нас народ любит YouTube) Банальный вопрос, где человек по сути сделал опечатку, его бы заминусовали и закрыли бы не будь там ютуба, но нет, ставим ютуб, показываем, что хотим скачать видео и сразу все "коршуны" пойдут лайкать по сути, бесполезный вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сохраняйте выбранный путь в некую переменную вашей формы и используйте в дальнейшем ее. А аргумент `result` из `downloadik_Click` нужно убрать, иначе он не может быть обработчиком события нажатия кнопки. Я добавил еще проверку, на то выбран путь или нет.

```
private string _curDirectorySave;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    folderDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
    folderDialog.SelectedPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    if (folderDialog.ShowDialog() == WinForms.DialogResult.OK)
         _curDirectorySave = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
}

private void downloadik_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_curDirectorySave))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Выберите путь сохранения");
        return;
    }
    string link = url.ToString();
    var youTube = YouTube.Default;

    var video = YouTube.Default.GetAllVideos(link).First(v => v.Resolution == 720);
    var audio = YouTube.Default.GetVideo(link);

    byte[] bytesvideo = video.GetBytes();
    File.WriteAllBytes(_curDirectorySave + video.FullName, bytesvideo); 
}
```

Comment: Человеческое спасибо! А что означает private? Я новичок в C#

Comment: @Tynett оу, я вам советую починать основы ООП т.к. C# на них основан. private помечаются члены классы доступные только внутри классы. И еще, раз вы используете WPF очень советую изучить MVVM паттерн, использование привязок и команд

Comment: @Tynett Если ответ вас устраивает, примите его нажмите плиз галку слева от ответа

Comment: `иначе он не может быть обработчиком события нажатия кнопки` - почему? Это можно спокойно обойти, аля `myButton.Click += (s, e) => Button_Click(s,e, "value");`.